# How do I get my ATL COM DLL IE plugin to work in Mozilla?

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, dll, plugins, mozilla

I have COM DLL(ATL Project) which handles the download dialog in IExplorer. I want that same DLL to work in Mozilla. What do I have to do for this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla and IE are using entirely different plug-in system. Basically you cannot simply do that.

Comment: then how to handle download in Mozilla? in iexplorer we have idownload manager interface to handle download dialog. What is the way to handle it in Mozilla?

Comment: actually i want to popup my own dialog instead of default mozilla. My dialog will save file on server with some additional feature.

Comment: i want that if user click in MOZILLA on any link it will pop of my dialog that handle download procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser (let us not forget Chrome, Safari, Opera, ...) has its own plugin/extensions mechanism.

You will need to create a different plugin for each browser based on that browser's API.

Perhaps if you explain your "additional features" you want on the file save then a different approach might be possible.